# composing map and filter for transducer

Tags: javascript, ramda.js

```
function add1(v) {
  return v + 1;
}

function isOdd(v) {
  return v % 2 == 1;
}

function sum(total, v) {
  return total + v;
}

const list = [1, 3, 4, 6, 9, 12, 13, 16, 21];

const list2 = list.map(add1).filter(isOdd).reduce(sum);
// 42

const transducer = R.compose(R.map(add1), R.filter(isOdd));
const list3 = R.transduce(transducer, sum, 0, list);
// 42

const transducer2 = R.compose(R.filter(isOdd), R.map(add1));
const list4 = R.transduce(transducer2, sum, 0, list);
// 52
```

I want to transduce map, filter, and reduce. (list2)

If compose is right-to-left, why isn't transducer2 resulting in 42?

Comment: Logging to the console each time one of the functions runs yields this for list4: 

1 "is odd";
"incrementing to" 2;
"adding " 2 "to" 0;
3 "is odd";
"incrementing to" 4;
"adding " 4 "to" 2;
9 "is odd";
"incrementing to" 10;
"adding " 10 "to" 6;
13 "is odd";
"incrementing to" 14;
"adding " 14 "to" 16;
21 "is odd";
"incrementing to" 22;
"adding " 22 "to" 30;

Comment: Composing transducers is left-to-right.  This is not technically true, but it is an easy way to think of them.  If you want the right-to-left behavior, switch to `pipe`.  Yes, I know that this seems backwards, but Ramda followed the already-existing behavior of Closure and some JS libraries.